Is it possible to create a Dialogflow project via REST or client?
Is it possible to create a Dialogflow project via REST or client?
I want to automate DialogFlow to use in chatbots, so it would be a nice feature to create the project automatically.
Perused the docs but didn't find anything.
Most things to be accessed need the project id beforehand.

Hi , you want to create dialogflow es agent via REST API ?  Manage agents with the API .
